# If there is a comment_author_link put url around the avatar image

Tags: comments

In the functions.php file for my theme the .commentslist shows a gravatar and if the user fills in a url in the comment form, you get a

```
comment_author_link()
```

Which prints a link with the name.

I want to put a link around the .avatar image IF there is a link. There is zip/zilch in the resources (https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=comment_author&post_type[]=wp-parser-function&post_type[]=wp-parser-hook&post_type[]=wp-parser-class&post_type[]=wp-parser-method).

It would be like this but this doesn't work:

```
<?php if ( has_comment_author_link() ) : ?>
  <a href="<?php echo comment_author_url();?>" target="_blank">
<?php endif; ?>

   <?php echo get_avatar( $comment, $size='75' ); ?>

<?php if ( has_comment_author_link() ) : ?>
  </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But there is no such "`has_comment_author_link`" and I don't know how to create this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
if( get_comment_author() == get_comment_author_link() )
    echo get_avatar( $comment, $size='75' );
else
    echo '<a href="' . get_comment_author_url . '">' . get_avatar( $comment, $size='75' ) . '</a>';
```