# Check if comment author has url

Tags: comments, comment-form

I wanted to add target=_blank to comment author link and also wanted to add redirection link to url.

So here is what I did:

```
<a href="site.com/go?url=<?php echo get_comment_author_url(); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_comment_author(); ?></a>
```

It works, but if comment author has no website I want to echo this:

```
<span><?php echo get_comment_author(); ?></span>
```

So, how to check if comment author entered url field?

Tried this but did not work:

```
    <?php if ( ! empty( $fields['url'] ) )  { ?>
```

**Solution**

Thanks to shanebp answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172156/136023)

```
<?php if( get_comment_author() == get_comment_author_link() ) 
                    comment_author_link();
                    else 
                     echo '<a href="site.com/go?url='. get_comment_author_url() .'" target="_blank">'. get_comment_author() .'</a>' ?>
```

Comment: You already have the access to `get_comment_author_url()` which returns either URL or empty string. What is the problem?

Comment: I want to add site.com/go?url= to author url. So when author url empty this still show up: site.com/go?url=

Comment: And what is the problem to check what does `get_comment_author_url()` return? Please interpret your question differently as it's completely unclear. what you are asking for.

Comment: I found solution `if( get_comment_author() == get_comment_author_link() )` does the job.

The problem was I add something to url, if url returns empty, still show up what I added.

Comment: If you have figured out the answer, then add your solution as an answer then mark it as correct. Answering your own question is encouraged.

Comment: I was not sure, if it was right thing to answer own question. Anyways I did now but can't mark as solved. System says I need to wait 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Thanks to shanebp answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172156/136023)

```
<?php if( get_comment_author() == get_comment_author_link() ) 
                    comment_author_link();
                    else 
                     echo '<a href="site.com/go?url='. get_comment_author_url() .'" target="_blank">'. get_comment_author() .'</a>' ?>
```